# Make a hierarchical tree from flat array of objects by field value

Tags: javascript, data-structures

Need to convert an array like:

```
[
  {value: 'a', depth: 1, children: []},
  {value: 'c', depth: 2, children: []},
  {value: 'd', depth: 2, children: []},
  {value: 'e', depth: 1, children: []},
  {value: 'f', depth: 2, children: []},
  {value: 'g', depth: 3, children: []},
  {value: 'i', depth: 4, children: []},
   // depth can bee any int but the integer row is respected 
  {value: 'j', depth: n, children: []},
   // ...
  {value: 'z', depth: 3, children: []},
]
```

into:

```
[
  {value: 'a', depth: 1, children: [
    {value: 'c', depth: 2, children: null},
    {value: 'd', depth: 2, children: null},
  ]},
  {value: 'e', depth: 1, children: [
    {value: 'f', depth: 2, children: [
      {value: 'g', depth: 3, children: [
        {value: 'i', depth: 4, children: [
          {value: 'j', depth: n, children: [
            // ...
          ]},
        ]},
      ]},
      {value: '', depth: 3, children: null},
    ]},
  ]},
]
```

Any help is **extremely appreciated**!

I understand I should use a recursive function but stuck here.

Comment: please add **where** you stuck.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post your code please and also the logic behind the hierarchy

Comment: How you will decide who are children of whom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a recursion. You could use a helper array for the levels and take the `depth` as a zero based value (this values need an adjustment).

The selection of parent children relation is based on order, so ever children follows the last parent of the previous depth element.

```js
var array = [{ value: 'a', depth: 1, children: [] }, { value: 'c', depth: 2, children: [] }, { value: 'd', depth: 2, children: [] }, { value: 'e', depth: 1, children: [] }, { value: 'f', depth: 2, children: [] }, { value: 'g', depth: 3, children: [] }, { value: 'i', depth: 4, children: [] }, { value: 'z', depth: 3, children: [] }],
    result = [],
    levels = [{ children: result }];

array.forEach(o => levels[o.depth - 1].children.push(levels[o.depth] = o));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Nina! You are genius )

Comment: Hm, what would I have to change to make this work if the depth can "skip" i.e. `1` to `3`?